# What is the difference between myDialog.dismiss() and myDialog.getDialog().dismiss()?

Tags: android, android-dialog

As i mentioned on title what is the difference between

this ..

```
public void dismissDialog(MyDialog dialog){
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

and this ..

```
public void dismissDialog(MyDialog dialog){
    dialog.getDialog().dismiss();
}
```

Which one should i use ? Or is there even a difference between them ?

**Edit 1:** MyDialog is a DialogFragment

Comment: Is `MyDialog` a `DialogFragment`?

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel yes it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment)

public void dismiss()

> Dismiss the fragment and its dialog. If the fragment was added to the
> back stack, all back stack state up to and including this entry will
> be popped. Otherwise, a new transaction will be committed to remove
> the fragment.

So `dismiss()` method not only close the dialog but also do the management of fragment transactions involved in the process. But `dialog.getDialog().dismiss()` will just dismiss dialog only.

**The correct way to close a DialogFragment is to use dismiss().**